# Could it be that 124 posts I upvoted are all deleted?

Tags: support, user-profile, up-votes

My [profile summary page](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/31260/gnat?tab=summary) currently says 3668 upvotes while votes->upvotes sub tab ([dev team only link](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/31260/gnat?tab=votes&sort=upvote)) counts less than that - 3544.

`3668-3544=124` - as far as I understand this difference could be [due to deleted posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/144757/165773), does that mean more than 100 posts I **upvoted** during last one and half year are **all** deleted?

Per my past observations deletion indeed decreases the count, I only don't know if there's anything else besides that could also cause the miss (eg like it was with expiration in [this bug report posted at MSO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/162044/profile-page-shows-6-reopen-votes-total-while-i-have-at-least-25-successful-ones)).

---

<sup>For the record, I also tried to check if this could somehow relate to deleted users but it appears to be not the case. My favorite ["good one-liner example"](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3477/31260) that was posted by now-deleted user shows my upvote just the way it was cast in April 2012.</sup>

Comment: I'm missing 300+ upvotes, if this turns out to be deletions I'll give those crazed moderators a talking to... Oh, wait!

Comment: @YannisRizos well as long as these all are **indeed** deletions (and not a result of **[some weird bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/162044/profile-page-shows-6-reopen-votes-total-while-i-have-at-least-25-successful-ones "like that")** that misses stuff) I wouldn't mind. Is there a way to somehow check that? I didn't mention but I've also got a few thousands _downvoted_ posts missing in a similar fashion. That is also (even more:) imaginable but I would like to make sure it's indeed so

Comment: Well, I guess you could point me to a couple of posts you've upvoted, I could delete them and see what happens (ping me in chat, we can fool around with each other's answers). But I've already ping a SE employee to see your question, this might be by design.

Comment: @YannisRizos thanks! if SE guy confirms this is by design, I'd be happy with that. BTW per my past observations deletion indeed decreases the count, I only don't know if there's anything else besides that could also cause the miss (like it was with vote expiration in bug report I referred to in prior comment)

Comment: related post at MSO: [“Votes cast” should include votes on deleted contributions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117846/votes-cast-should-include-votes-on-deleted-contributions)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have up-voted 124 deleted posts. Such votes do show up in your totals, [and also count toward various badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117846/votes-cast-should-include-votes-on-deleted-contributions/123048#123048); they have the additional advantage of *not* counting toward the daily voting limit.

They *don't* show up on your profile's votes tab, because that would mean showing you links to deleted posts - that would equate to giving you broken links on your profile which would be *bad*.

For comparison, you've *down-voted* 4,587 deleted posts.

Comment: Will that behavior change when gnat clears the 10k reputation threshold?

Comment: Interestingly, *no* - deleted posts are never shown on the votes tab, regardless of how much reputation the owner has.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I would file a bug request on that except I couldn't prove it at my current reputation.  ;-)

Comment: I don't know that I'd consider this a bug - IIRC, the only place we display deleted posts anywhere on a profile are the favorites and reputation pages, and for the latter you have to opt-in; generally-speaking, it's something we try to avoid.

Comment: thanks, these numbers make a perfect proof that things work as I expected

Comment: _"deleted posts are never shown"_ makes good sense for arbitrarily high rep user because my understanding is, these are **intended** to be available only by direct link. Any sort of "list" would kind of trash the purpose

Comment: @gnat: right - like I said, there are only two places I'm aware of where you *can* see them, and those are sorta anomalous (i.e., probably mistakes).

Comment: Well, there's the flag history page too - that can contain quite a lot of links to deleted contents. (/cc @gnat)

Comment: (And yes, two years later) just noting that links to deleted posts *are* visible to 10k users on the close, reopen, delete, and undelete vote tabs.  The only vote tabs that *don't* show deleted posts are up and down.

Comment: Yeah, we *finally* fixed that a little while ago (after getting massively sidetracked on the first attempt) @MichaelT